# How to best sum by area

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

Below is the sample data.

```
library(tidyverse)

  area <- c("003","003","003","003","003","003","003","003","017","017","017","017","017","017","017","017")
  year <- c("2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022","2022")
  period <- c("01","01","01","01","02","02","02","02","01","01","01","01","02","02","02","02")
  naics <- c("231","331","341","421","231","331","341","421","231","331","341","421","231","331","341","421")
  m1 <- c(100,105,110,152,102,107,112,155,42,45,52,61,39,47,55,100)
  m2 <- c(101,106,111,153,103,108,111,156,40,44,53,62,40,48,56,98)
  m3 <- c(102,107,112,155,104,109,112,157,43,46,55,63,41,49,57,95)


  first <- data.frame(area,year,period, naics,m1,m2,m3)

  first <- first %>% group_by(area,year,qtr, naics) %>% mutate (avgemp = mean(m1:m3))
```

The desired goal is to create a new row for each combination of year, qtr, naics, and area. This would be an area total of sorts.  The new naics would 000000 (naics for total, all industries). do I have to do a pivot longer for this?

Desired result is below

```
  area      year      period     naics     m1     m2     m3     avgemp
  003       2022       01       000000    467    471    476      471
  003       2022       02       000000    476    478    482      479
  017       2022       01       000000    200    199    207      202
  and so on....
```

Comment: Your example data throws an error: Column `qtr` is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by grouping the data and then you can create a new row with naics = "000000" to represent the total across industries:

```
first %>%
  group_by(area, year, period) %>%
  summarize(m1 = sum(m1),
            m2 = sum(m2),
            m3 = sum(m3),
            avgemp = sum(avgemp)) %>%
  mutate(naics = "000000")
```

Output:

```
# Groups:   area, year [2]
  area  year  period    m1    m2    m3 avgemp naics 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> 
1 003   2022  01       467   471   476   472. 000000
2 003   2022  02       476   478   482   479  000000
3 017   2022  01       200   199   207   204. 000000
4 017   2022  02       241   242   242   242. 000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first %>%
  group_by(area,year,period) %>%
  summarize(across(m1:m3, sum), .groups = "drop") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(avgemp = mean(m1:m3), naics = "000000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(first)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(area, year, period),
  .SDcols = patterns("^m\\d+")][, c("avgemp", "naics") := .(rowMeans(.SD, 
    na.rm = TRUE), strrep("0", 5)), .SDcols = patterns("^m\\d+")][]
```

-output

```
   area year period  m1  m2  m3   avgemp naics
1:  003 2022     01 467 471 476 471.3333 00000
2:  003 2022     02 476 478 482 478.6667 00000
3:  017 2022     01 200 199 207 202.0000 00000
4:  017 2022     02 241 242 242 241.6667 00000
```